# Is there a way to sequence scala's function using foldLeft or any other list method?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to sequence a list of functions, these functions are define in an companion object:

```
object solution {

def methodA(l: List[String]): List[Int] = {
  l.map(_.toInt)
}

def methodB(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  l.map(_ + 1)
}

def methodC(l: List[Int]): Long = {
  l.sum
}
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val f1 = this.methodA _
  val f2 = this.methodB _
  val f3 = this.methodC _
  val fs = f1 andThen f2 andThen f3
  fs.apply(List("1", "2", "3"))
}
}
```

What I want is this style:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fs = List(f1, f2, f3)
    fs.foldLeft(someFunc).apply(List("1", "2", "3"))
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you want to happen? Like is each element of the `List("1", "2", "3")` the input for the functions `f1, `f2` & `f3` respectively? Or you want to pass the list itself as the input of all functions? Or you want to pass the List as the output of `f1` and the result of that to `f2` and then the result of that to `f3`? - BTW, why the ouput is **Unit**? _(also it would help if you share the type of each function)_.

Comment: The problem is that since each function have different types, is not possible to do this in a generic way for many functions. I suppose that if you want some kind of folding, is because you have many many functions _(not just three)_, Do you control those functions?

Comment: Actually, I just want to implement Pipeline pattern, which one result 'flow' into another's input :)

Comment: Scala `2.13` has a package [`util.chaining`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/package$$chaining$.html) which allows you to write something like `List(1, 2, 3) pipe f1 pipe f2 pipe f3`. If you are in `2.12` you can copy and paste the code, is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do it only if all functions have the same type.

```
  type A = String
  type B = String
  type C = String
  type D = String

  val f1: A => B = identity
  val f2: B => C = identity
  val f3: C => D = identity

  val ls: List[String => String] = List(f1, f2, f3)

  val aggregate: String => String = ls.reduceLeft(_ andThen _)

  aggregate.apply(...)
```

This is because Scala compiler would infer the type of list to be supertype of all values in the list, which for single argument functions is `Nothing => Any`, now you cannot sequence a list of `Nothing => Any` into one composed function, for the ends and beginnings don't match up, the only case where they do is when the argument and the return type are both the same.